# Unable to boot into BIOS/Post while graphics card is plugged in

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I just got a problem with my computer which I cannot resolve.

So basically, Today when I tried to turn on my computer, it wouldn't even boot to BIOS/POST and there was no display on the monitor. All the fans were working and the lights on mother board were getting lighted up. It was working fine till yesterday and I usually game 6-10 hrs everyday. I thought it had something to do with the RAM sticks so I replaced them but it didn't work. After that I removed my graphics card and tried to boot my computer without it and it did. I installed my graphics card back and I faced the same problem. Could it be a problem with my graphics card or my PSU ? The fan on graphics card is working. Can excessive gaming (6-10hrs / day) cause the graphics card to get damaged ? I am not overclocking anything. I have been using this setup for 3-4 years and it has been working well since then. Also running the games on optimal settings and not pushing the GPU beyond its limits. I would really appreciate your help on this problem.

Specifications:

1. ASUS P8Z77-V LK
2. Intel Core i3 2100
3. Kingston HyperX Fury DDR3 (2x 4GB)
4. [HIS HD 7970](http://www.hisdigital.com/un/product2-678.shtml)
5. Cooler Master Extreme 2 625Watts
6. Chassis: Cooler Master HAF 912 Advanced

Comment: This can be anything really. It could be the graphics card. It could also be that its working fine, but somehow the output changed to the onboard graphics card. It requires more testing. For example, if you place that GPU in a different computer, does it work there?

Comment: Don't really have another computer. But i also tried plugging my HDMI cable to On board connector But got nothing. One more thing i tested out that If i left the card plugged in But removed the PCIe Power Connector then the computer would just boot fine. But the graphics card wasn't detected

Answer (score 0):

Look at the back of your computer and see if it has a cover over a connector for the motherboard graphics device.  If so, remove that cover, move the graphics cable to that connector, and try to boot.  If it boots, read the instructions for that computer or its motherboard, looking for a way to turn off use of the motherboard graphics device and therefore switch back to using the graphics card.